# How Windows 8 and Windows 10 hash account password?

Tags: hash, windows-10, windows-8

I need some accurate information about how Windows 8 and Windows 10  perform hashing user account passwords.

I know that they are stored in SAM file and NTLMv2 algorithm is used. But while using some utilities like `pwdump` I don’t understand for example why Windows 8 output looks something like:

```
<account name>: id NO PASSWORD: ***** :<hash>
```

and for Windows 10:

```
<account name>: id <hash1> :<hash2>.
```

Is there some good and accurate explonation of how these systemes hash user account passwords?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you mean by using `pwdump`? There are a lot of tools just called `pwdump` or tools that have a `pwdump` command

Comment: @Mr.E, i have used tool from this site: http://www.tarasco.org/security/pwdump_7/.

Comment: As a best practice, please update the original question as clarification questions/answers are added to comments. It helps others jump into the problem with a lower barrier to entry.

Comment: @primohacker, okay, i am a beginner, sorry) will do my best!

Comment: No worries, it’s just helpful.